# Can't figure out how to Get rid of NaN

Tags: java, android

Ok so i am bulding this application that calculates 3 input boxes. i am getting a NaN when doing some calculations with 0 values.
here is the main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>


<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:id="@+id/ScrollView01" >




<AbsoluteLayout android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent">



    <EditText android:id="@+id/InputNumber01"
        android:numeric="integer|decimal" android:imeOptions="actionNext"
        android:textStyle="bold" android:hint="Service Call"
        android:layout_x="5dip" android:layout_y="5px" android:layout_height="55dip"
        android:textSize="20dip" android:layout_width="195dip"
        android:selectAllOnFocus="true" android:inputType="numberDecimal"/>



    <EditText android:id="@+id/InputNumber02"
        android:numeric="integer|decimal" android:inputType="numberDecimal"
        android:textStyle="bold" android:hint="Parts" android:layout_x="5dip"
        android:layout_y="90px" android:layout_height="55dip"
        android:textSize="20dip" android:layout_width="195dip"
        android:selectAllOnFocus="true" android:imeOptions="actionNext"/>



    <EditText android:id="@+id/InputNumber03" android:numeric="integer|decimal"
        android:inputType="numberDecimal" android:textStyle="bold"
        android:hint="Labor" android:layout_x="5dip" android:layout_y="175px"
        android:layout_height="55dip" android:textSize="20dip"
        android:layout_width="195dip" android:selectAllOnFocus="true"
        android:imeOptions="actionDone"/>

    <Button android:text="Calculate" android:id="@+id/actionButton"

        android:textStyle="bold" android:layout_height="50dip"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_y="300px"
        android:textSize="15dip" />


    <TextView android:id="@+id/TextResult" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:numeric="integer|decimal" android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_width="85dip" android:layout_x="225dip"
        android:layout_y="175dip" android:gravity="left" android:textSize="18dip"
        android:textColor="#1d9ee2" />



    <TextView android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/TextView04"
        android:text="Total:" android:textStyle="bold" android:gravity="right"
        android:layout_width="55dip" android:layout_y="175dip"
        android:layout_x="165dip" android:textSize="18dip" />

    <TextView android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/TextView05"
        android:text="Total Labor:" android:layout_y="260dip"
        android:layout_width="95dip" android:layout_x="5dip" android:gravity="right" />

    <TextView android:text="@+id/TotalLabor"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/TotalLabor" android:layout_y="260dip"
        android:layout_x="110dip" />

    <TextView android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/TextView06"
        android:layout_x="5dip" android:text="Total Services:"
        android:layout_y="280dip" android:layout_width="95dip"
        android:gravity="right" />

    <TextView android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/TotalServices"
        android:text="@+id/TotalServices" android:layout_y="280dip"
        android:layout_x="110dip" />

    <TextView android:id="@+id/TextView07" android:text="SC Tax %:"
        android:layout_y="300dip" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_x="5dip" android:layout_width="95dip" android:gravity="right" />

    <TextView android:text="@+id/TextView08"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/SCTaxPercent" android:layout_y="300dip"
        android:layout_x="110dip" />

    <TextView android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/TextView08"
        android:text="Sales Tax:" android:textStyle="bold" android:layout_y="175dip"
        android:layout_x="5dip" android:textSize="18dip"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:gravity="right" />

    <TextView android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/SalesTax"
        android:textStyle="bold" android:numeric="integer|decimal"
        android:layout_y="175dip" android:gravity="left"
        android:layout_width="65dip" android:textSize="18dip"
        android:layout_x="100dip" />

    <TextView android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/TextView09"
        android:text="SC Taxable:" android:layout_y="320dip"
        android:layout_x="5dip" android:layout_width="95dip" android:gravity="right" />

    <TextView android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="@+id/TextView10"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/ScTaxable"
        android:layout_y="320dip" android:layout_x="110dip" />

    <TextView android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/TextView10"
        android:text="Taxable:" android:layout_y="340dip"
        android:layout_width="95dip" android:layout_x="5dip" android:gravity="right" />

    <TextView android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="@+id/TextView11"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/Taxable"
        android:layout_y="340dip" android:layout_x="110dip" />

    <EditText android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="9.50"
        android:layout_width="90dip" android:id="@+id/SalesTaxValue"
        android:layout_x="5dip" android:layout_y="430dip" android:numeric="integer|decimal"
        android:selectAllOnFocus="true" />

    <TextView android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/TextView01"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_x="5dip"
        android:text="Sales Tax Value:" android:layout_y="407dip" />
</AbsoluteLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

and this is the calculator.java

```
package com.Eddie.TaxCalculator;

import java.text.NumberFormat;

import com.Eddie.TaxCalculator.R;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class Calculator extends Activity {
    private Button calculateButton;
    private EditText inputField01;
    private EditText inputField02;
    private EditText inputField03;
    private EditText salesTaxValue;
    private double serviceCall;
    private double parts;
    private double labor;
    private double salestaxvalue;


String zero ="0";

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        calculateButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.actionButton);
        calculateButton.setOnClickListener(doSomethingNow);
        this.getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_VISIBLE);

        }

    private OnClickListener doSomethingNow = new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            inputField01 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.InputNumber01);
            inputField02 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.InputNumber02);
            inputField03 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.InputNumber03);
            salesTaxValue = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.SalesTaxValue);


            if (inputField01.getText().toString().length()==0)
                    {
                       inputField01.setText(zero);
                    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), 
                            "Service Call TextBox was empty.",
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                    toast.show();
                    }       
            if(inputField02.getText().toString().length()==0)
                    {
                       inputField02.setText(zero);
                    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), 
                            "Parts TextBox was empty.",
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                    toast.show();
                    }   
            if(inputField03.getText().toString().length()==0)
                    {
                       inputField03.setText(zero);
                    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), 
                            "Labor TextBox was empty.",
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                    toast.show();
                    }
            //service Call is 0
            if (inputField01.getText().toString().equals("0"))
            {
            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), 
                    "Service Call TextBox value is 0.",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            //toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL, 0, 0);
            toast.show();
            }       
            //Parts is 0
                if (inputField02.getText().toString().equals("0"))
            {
               //inputField01.setText("10");
            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), 
                    "Parts TextBox value is 0.",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            toast.show();
            }   
            //Labor is 0
            if (inputField03.getText().toString().equals("0"))
            {
               //inputField01.setText("10");
            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), 
                    "Labor TextBox value is 0.",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            toast.show();
            }   


            serviceCall = Double.parseDouble(inputField01.getText().toString());
            parts = Double.parseDouble(inputField02.getText().toString());
            labor = Double.parseDouble(inputField03.getText().toString());
            salestaxvalue = Double.parseDouble(salesTaxValue.getText().toString());

            NumberFormat numberFormat = NumberFormat.getInstance();
            numberFormat.setMaximumFractionDigits(2);            
            numberFormat.setGroupingUsed(false); 



            TextView totalLabor = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.TotalLabor);
            Double totalLaborResults =  serviceCall +  labor;
            String totalLaborCalcInt = numberFormat.format(totalLaborResults).toString();
            totalLabor.setText (totalLaborCalcInt);

            TextView totalServices = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.TotalServices);
            Double totalServicesResults = (parts + labor);
            String totalServicesCalcInt = numberFormat.format(totalServicesResults);
            totalServices.setText (totalServicesCalcInt);


            TextView servicecallTaxpercent = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.SCTaxPercent);
            Double scTaxPercentResults =  (parts / totalServicesResults);
            String serviceCallPercentCalcInt =  numberFormat.format(scTaxPercentResults).toString();
            servicecallTaxpercent.setText (serviceCallPercentCalcInt);

            TextView scTaxable = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.ScTaxable);
            Double scTaxableResults = (serviceCall * scTaxPercentResults);
            String serviceCallTaxableCalcInt =numberFormat.format (scTaxableResults).toString();
            scTaxable.setText (serviceCallTaxableCalcInt);

            TextView taxable = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.Taxable);
            Double taxableResults = (parts + scTaxableResults);             
            String taxableCalcInt =numberFormat.format (taxableResults).toString();
            taxable.setText (taxableCalcInt);

            TextView salesTax = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.SalesTax);
            Double salesTaxResults = (taxableResults * salestaxvalue) /100;
            String salesTaxCalcInt = numberFormat.format (salesTaxResults).toString();
            salesTax.setText (salesTaxCalcInt);

            TextView textResult = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.Total);
            Double additionResults = (salesTaxResults + parts+ serviceCall +  labor);
            String TotalCalcInt = numberFormat.format(additionResults).toString();
            textResult.setText (TotalCalcInt);

                }

    };

};
```

when entering a number in input 1 (service Call) and zeros in the two other inputs i get a NaN Total.

if All input Boxes are zero value i also get a NaN total, NaN sale Tax, NaN scTax % textview (sc is short of Service Call) 
NaN scTaxable, NaN taxable.

could anyone help me find this but i've been trying for two weeks now. 
pls help.

Comment: Did you post your whole XML file?  If not you are missind the `xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"` in the absolute layout tag and also `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>` should be at the very first line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If parts is 0 and labor is 0 then totalServicesResults is 0 and scTaxPercentsResults is infinite.

Comment: all i wanted is to get a 0 instead of NaN is there anyway to get the answer to be 0

Comment: if(parts == 0) scTaxPercentResults = 0 else scTaxPercentResults =  (parts / totalServicesResults); // This should work only because totalServiceResults include parts.

Answer (score 2):

I mean, dividing by 0 is not something that makes sense, so... just don't do it.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is definitely using zero (0) values as Input...

Although, i see you trying to catch such instances with

```
xxxx.getText().toString().equals("0")
```

1) This is not a good way, to check for zero...imagine what will happen if i type in `00` or `000`....

2) After you display the `Toast`, *you go ahead and do the calculations* **anyway**...Use the `if-else` branching logic to avoid the calculation when the values are zero.

To Correctly Check for zero...you need to Parse it into a datatype (`Double` in your case) and then check for its value....

Goodluck, Cheers!

Comment: see totalServicesResults  is a textview that adds Parts and labor. and parts is divided by scTaxPercentsResults i really don't know how to control not deviding by 0 if parts and labor is 0 value. the toast is used only for info. thank for looking into this

Comment: @Eddie, I suggest, right before dividing...you add an additional `if` condition, checking if hte denominator is 0....if it is, avoid calculating further and dimiss gracefully using a toast.

Answer (score 1):

Divide by zero returns NaN when done on floats/doubles. Check that the divider is not zero before the division.

Comment: thank you, i know the problem is in this block  
            TextView servicecallTaxpercent = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.SCTaxPercent);
            Double scTaxPercentResults =  (parts / totalServicesResults);
            String serviceCallPercentCalcInt =  numberFormat.format(scTaxPercentResults).toString();
            servicecallTaxpercent.setText (serviceCallPercentCalcInt);         can you tell me what can i do about it. if the  totalServicesResults is a 0 through calculation how can i get rid of NaN? thanks Eli

Comment: Before doing the division, check if `totalServicesResults == 0`. If it is, set result to be 0 (or whatever other value that is appropriate logically).